# How to use php between html tag?

Tags: php, html

I know and just checked there are lot of answers of this question. But I feel I have to ask myself with my specific example. Here goes the example:

```
<?php if($i==1){?><div class=yel><?php echo "Today at $hour:$min $ampm<br/> Event: $event<br/> Place: $place<br/> Description: $desp<br/> Contact info: $info";?></div><?php } ?>
```

It worked in my pc but when I was trying this code in other pc it got error(parse, syntax). Trust me I tried on several computers. But no result. And the same code is working fine in my pc.

So at last I come to a decision that my code is not neat and clean at all. So there may be something wrong with my code that I couldn't notice. You see I start & end PHP block again and again. You know well why I did that. Actually I am trying to avoid the  tag within php block. So my question is, IS THERE ANY MORE EFFICIENT WAY TO USE DIV TAG OR ANY OTHER TAG WITHIN PHP BLOCK? Advance thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this much simplier to understand by eye?

```
<?php 

if($i==1){
    echo "<div class=yel>";
    echo "Today at $hour:$min $ampm<br/> Event: $event<br/> Place: $place<br/> Description: $desp<br/> Contact info: $info";
    echo "</div>";
}


?>
```

Comment: Yes it is. So I don't need to start and end the php block again and again. You just used only one php block and also you put div tag into echo. I didn't know it that div tag works in echo. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

use a colon instead of brackets. also close it with `endif`.

```
<?php if($i == 1): ?>
    <div class=yel>
        <?php echo "Today at $hour:$min $ampm<br/> Event: $event<br/> Place: $place<br/> Description: $desp<br/> Contact info: $info";?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can also use short tags (which require being enabled via php.ini) to make things cleaner.

```
<? if($i == 1): ?>
    <div class=yel>
        <?="Today at $hour:$min $ampm<br/> Event: $event<br/> Place: $place<br/> Description: $desp<br/> Contact info: $info"?>
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Here I noticed you used a '=' instead of echo. So it's another new thing to me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use if and endif:

```
<?php if($i==1): ?>
<div class=yel>
<?php 
echo "Today at $hour:$min $ampm<br/> Event: $event<br/> Place: $place<br/> Description: $desp<br/> Contact info: $info";
?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Though personally I would use MAXIM's answer

Comment: So me too. Thanks Christopher.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with a heredoc:

```
if($i == 1) echo <<< HTML
    <div class="yel">
        Today at {$hour}:{$min} {$ampm}<br/>
        Event: {$event}<br/>
        Place: {$place}<br/>
        Description: {$desp}<br/>
        Contact info: {$info}
    </div>
HTML;
```

When you have a handful of HTML containing a few variables heredocs are kind of made for it. Nice and clean.